# Why are my hosta leaves dying?

Tags: hosta

Am I over watering these ? Is it too much sun? They get sun in the afternoon starting with around 2-3PM till around 7PM in July. Very hot weather this year but I remember having the same issue last year. On the other side I have hostas in the front of the house and they start showing burnings as well during the summer

The worst one looks like this
[image]

I think this is what I bought ...if the variety matters
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, they are likely getting too much sun. They prefer mostly shade, with a moist but not overwet soil, preferably rich in organic material. Mulching helps conserve moisture. Hot afternoon sun is not ideal for them. They should be on the north side of the house, or under trees.

Comment: What I have seen in reality and this post here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/26641/can-i-propagate-a-hosta-from-a-leaf?rq=1 contradicts what you are saying...they grow everywhere

Comment: As I noted in your other question, your hosta is a blue-leaved variety, which are NOT very sun-tolerant. @DCookie is correct.

Comment: I've always subscribed to the school of thought that plants will tell you if they can tolerate conditions. This hosta looks sunburnt and unhappy. To test it, you could make a temporary shade cloth tent for it and see how it does.

Comment: I took out a cherry tree and exposed 6 hosta to full sun for half of each day. They quickly began to look like those pictured. A fast move to a shadier location saved them.

Comment: I think it depends on the variety...I am seeing hostas in my neighborhood doing just fine in full sun